# adb install [app_name] - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

Tags: adb

Firstly I'm aware that this has been asked many many times, but I've tried all those answers and still no luck. Let me explain.

I have 2 apps, 1 stock app, and one with the fino tool added in (sysdream/fino). This all repackaged correctly and was resigned correctly however when I try:

```
adb install app_fino.apk 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

And adb install -r, which is obvious as I added fino to it and resigned.

```
 adb install -r app_fino.apk
 Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
```

Other answers said to Uninstall and then reinstall the new app. So headed over to Apps > All > Uninstalled

...Rebooted phone

```
 adb install app_fino.apk 
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I uninstalled, but then changed the Bundle Identifier from Unity (for android), and now it won't install. I believe it might have to do with the Bundle ID being changed, and timing of uninstall

Answer (score 2):

Try this command to uninstall:

```
adb uninstall com.your.packagename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still get the `INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS` message even after an

```
adb uninstall com.your.packagename
```

The application may still be present on the system partition and thus cannot be removed using `adb uninstall`.
To fix this you need to also remove the original system app (can only be done on a rooted device):

```
adb shell
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw /system
# cd /system/data
# rm OffendingPackage.apk
```

Note that the package names in the system folder not necessarily follow the `com.your.packagename.apk` convention. So you may need to look around a bit for the correct apk.

Finally `adb reboot` the device before trying to install again.